# How to create Post request having form data of azure blob file in Http trigger Azure function given file's SAS uri and token

Tags: asp.net, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-form-recognizer

Create Post request having form data of azure blob file in Http trigger Azure function given file's SAS uri and token.

I have Http triggered azure function in which I want to call an post method of API. In the post request I have to pass a file available on my azure blob of which I have SAS uri and token.
I tried something like below but it didn't worked out as API endpoint is expecting file in post request.

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri(uri),
            Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                form = formUrl, //SAS uri with token
                type = "application/pdf"
            }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
        })
        {

            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException($"The remote service {uri} responded with a {response.StatusCode} error code instead of the expected 202 Accepted.");
                }
                return response.Headers.GetValues("Operation-Location").FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, the post API is working through Postman if I upload local file in form body. The difference between postman call and through code is just that in postman I am uploading file using fileupload whereas in azure function SAS uri of file is passed.

The post call is actually to latest version (4.0) of Azure Form Recognizer

Answer (score 1):

- Since you already have the blob URL you can directly make a rest Api call to form recognizer.
- But before that make sure that CORS is enabled in your storage account and the container in which you have your blob must have public access.
- Now here you have to set the headers `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`  and `Content-Type` with their values set to a key from the form recognizer and to `application/json` respectively
- In the body of the post request you will add a JSON object as

```
{
    "source":"<Your url of blob >"
}
```

- Also add a parameter called endpoint it values you can get from portal
- Now you will need auth tokens to make the request. You can get the token if you click on `tryit`   in this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/formrecognizer/2.0/analyze-layout-async/analyze-layout-async?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) it will ask you to login in then fill the subsequent form will with details mentioned above and it will give you a preview from where you can get the token without needing to set up a service principle.
  [image]

But this token will be for you only, for production you will have to set a service principle (azure ad app) and get tokens using `DefaultAzureCredential().getokens()`

complete code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(<URL of Your api>);
var content = new StringContent(SourceString,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,"application/json" );

///Here SourceString is an object which represent a string called source 

HttpRequestMessage reqq = new HttpRequestMessage();
reqq.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",<You KEY for form recogniser>);
reqq.Content = content;

reqq.Headers.Add("Authorization", <token>);

HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(reqq);
```

[image]

Here the `202` will represent that the operation was successfull.

Refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/formrecognizer/2.0/analyze-layout-async/analyze-layout-async?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) on which is a form recognizer api.